# Is $\cosh(z)\exp(iz)+ \sin(i\overline{z})\exp(z)$ complex differentiable.

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

> Is $$f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}, \quad z \mapsto f(z) := \cosh(z)\exp(iz)+ \sin(i\overline{z})\exp(z)$$ complex differentiable?

I found this question in a sample exam for complex analysis and couldn't figure out a solution yet. I first tried to split the complex trigonometric functions into real and imag. part, and use the Cauchy-Riemann equations. This ended up in a huge term, so I guess theres a much faster way, which I fail to see.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Products of holomorphic functions and sums of holomorphic functions are holomorphic. The first summand is holomorphic, so $f$ is holomorphic if and only if the second summand is. The second summand is holomorphic if and only if its product with $\exp(-z)$ is.

Answer (score 2):

If it were, so would be $\sinh \bar{z}$. But nontrivial nice functions of $\bar{z}$ like that aren't analytic. If you want to complete that step of the proof rigourously, show it fails the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so I'd just go with: $\sin(i\overline{z}) = \cosh(x) \sin(y) + i \sinh(x)\cos(y) = u(x,y) +i v(x,y)$ . As we see $\frac{du}{dx}= \sinh(x)\sin(y) \neq \frac{dv}{dy}= -\sinh(x)\sin(y)$.